# Setting airflow connections using Values.yaml in Helm (Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, databricks, kubernetes-helm

Airflow Version - 2.3.0
Helm Chart - Apache-airflow/airflow

I have been working on setting up airflow using helm on kubernetes.
Currently, I am planning to set airflow connections using the values.yaml file and env variables instead of configuring them up on the webUI.

I believe the settings to tweak, to set the connections, are:

```
extraSecrets: {}
# eg:
# extraSecrets:
#   '{{ .Release.Name }}-airflow-connections':
#     type: 'Opaque'
#     data: |
#       AIRFLOW_CONN_GCP: 'base64_encoded_gcp_conn_string'
#       AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS: 'base64_encoded_aws_conn_string'
#     stringData: |
#       AIRFLOW_CONN_OTHER: 'other_conn'
#   '{{ .Release.Name }}-other-secret-name-suffix':
#     data: |
#        ...
```

I am not sure how to set all the key-value pairs for a databricks/emr connection, and how to use the kubernetes secrets (already set up as env vars in pods) to get the values

```
#extraSecrets:
#  '{{ .Release.Name }}-airflow-connections':
#    type: 'Opaque'
#    data:
#      AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT_two:
#         conn_type: "emr"
#         host: <host_url>
#         extra:
#          token: <token string>
#          host: <host_url>
```

It would be great to get some insights on how to resolve this issue

I looked up this link : [managing_connection on airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#json-format-example)

Tried Changes in values.yaml file:

```
#extraSecrets:
#  '{{ .Release.Name }}-airflow-connections':
#    type: 'Opaque'
#    data:
#      AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT_two:
#         conn_type: "emr"
#         host: <host_url>
#         extra:
#          token: <token string>
#          host: <host_url>
```

Error Occurred:
**While updating helm release:**
`extraSecrets.{{ .Release.Name }}-airflow-connections expects string, got object`

Comment: Does your extraSecrets look exactly as you've posted i.e. with #? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/parameters-ref.html has an example that you can refer to.

Comment: I added the connection by providing json type object to the AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT key, but it raised an error, so commented it out. Also, I can't find an example of adding multiple keys to the connection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow connections can be set using Kubernetes secrets and env variables.

For setting secrets, directly from the cli, the easiest way is to

- Create a kubernetes secret

  - The secret value (connection string) has to be in the URI format suggested by airflow

    **`my-conn-type://login:password@host:port/schema?param1=val1&param2=val2`**
- Create an env variable in the airflow-suggested-format

  - Airflow format for connection - AIRFLOW_CONN_{connection_name in all CAPS}
- set the value of the connection env variable using the secret

How to manage airflow connections: [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html)

Example,
To set the default databricks connection (databricks_default)in airflow -

- create secret

```
    kubectl create secret generic airflow-connection-databricks \
        --from-literal=AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT='databricks://@<DATABRICKS_HOST>?token=<DATABRICKS_TOKEN>'
```

- In helm's (values.yaml), add new env variable using the secret:

```
    envName: "AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT"
                secretName: "airflow-connection-databricks"
                secretKey: "AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABRICKS_DEFAULT"
```

Some useful links:

- [Managing Airflow connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html)
- [Databricks databricks connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/2.0.0/connections/databricks.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20to,account%20to%20the%20Airflow%20connection.)

Comment: This is how you can generate the connection URI: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#generating-a-connection-uri

Answer (score 0):

Airflow supports setting connections via URI only in the helm chart.
The easiest way to get the URI is create the connection in the Webserver UI in the normal way and then after, SSH into the running webserver container and execute the command

```
airflow connections get <created_connection_id>
```

You will obtain the URI.

URI: `sqlite://%2Ftmp%2Fsqlite_default.db`

- Now follow the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399085/setting-airflow-connections-using-values-yaml-in-helm-kubernetes/74504137#74504137) to create the kubernetes secret with the URI.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399085/setting-airflow-connections-using-values-yaml-in-helm-kubernetes/74504137#74504137)

Comment: Not exactly - `get_uri` will not contain all the information, however the whole URI can be built from this point.